# After Insert Trigger never fires using Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server, trigger, import

Using Import Wizard I tried importing tables `tcc_Block` and `PROJECT_IDENTITY`.

These 2 table structures already exist in SQL Server and they are related with `ProjectID` columns.  `PROJECT_IDENTITY` has `ProjectID` as PK and `tcc_Block` as FK key.

Any time I import tables, `ProjectID` in parent table is created and incremented, but the one in child table is always Null.

The trigger never fires!?

```
-- On tcc_Block table I need to do the update (below) AFTER INSERT
-- Tried Trigger, but none would work.

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTest]
ON [dbo].[tcc_Block]
AFTER INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @proj int;

    SELECT @proj =max(ProjectID) 
    FROM PROJECT_IDENTITY ;

    UPDATE tcc_Block
    SET ProjectID = @proj
    WHERE ProjectID is null ;

END;
GO
```

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

The [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) does not expose a way to enable triggers directly.

You could save the result as an SSIS package, then [edit that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844220/440595) to enable the `FIRE_TRIGGERS` option in the component it uses.

Alternatively, and probably more simply, you could choose to use one of the other data import methods that more easily allow you to specify that triggers should be fired.

Related official documentation:

[Bulk Import and Export of Data (SQL Server)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx)
[Controlling Trigger Execution When Bulk Importing Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx)